# How to send bulk email by click button at one time using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

How to send bulk email by clicking button at one time using codeigniter...I got an error while doing bulk email in codeigniter.I need to rectify this one..i need help for this problem

***This is my controller***

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Send_all extends CI_Controller {
 public function __construct()
 {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->database();
$this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
$this->load->model('user_model');
$this->load->model('Gst_model');
$this->load->model('Report_model');  
 }

public function index($email_cript, $vendor_id)
{
$VendorEmail = base64_decode($email_cript);
$this->db->where('VendorEmail', $VendorEmail);
$query=$this->db->get('gst_vendormaster');
$cust_details= $query->result();
$data['cust_details'] = $cust_details;
//$mail_to = "$VendorEmail";
//$mail_count= count($mail_to);
 $to_mail = explode(',', $VendorEmail);
         $mail_count= count($to_mail);
for($VendorEmail=0;$VendorEmail < $mail_count;$VendorEmail++)
{

$data['VendorEmail'] = $cust_details[0]->VendorEmail;
 print_r($VendorEmail);
$config = array(
'protocol' => 'sendmail',
'mailtype' => 'html',
'charset' => 'UTF-8',
);

$this->load->library('email');
 $this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$mail_id = TRIM($to_mail[$VendorEmail]);
 $message =
 '<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table class="body" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">&nbsp;</span></span></td>
<td class="container" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; display: block; margin: 0 auto !important; max-width: 580px; padding: 10px; width: 580px;" valign="top" width="580">
<div class="content" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 580px; padding: 10px;">
<table class="main" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,2); width: 100%; background: #fff; border-radius: 3px;" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="wrapper" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px;" valign="top">
<table style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
<p><img src="http://www.miisky.com/ci/GST.png" alt="" width="85" height="84" />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<strong>GST - IMPLEMENTATION &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="http://www.aarmsvaluechain.com/images/value-chain.png" alt="" width="98" height="84" />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong></p>
<p>Dear Sir / Madam,</p>
<p>As you are aware, the Government of India introduced Good and Service Tax (&ldquo;GST&rdquo;) in August, 2016 which will subsume the existing indirect taxes in India such as value added tax (&ldquo;VAT&rdquo;), service tax, central excise, entertainment tax, entry tax etc..&nbsp;</p>
<p>As part of the GST regime, various state governments have initiated the GST enrolment process of existing VAT taxpayer registered with various State VAT departments. Accordingly, we would request you to confirm if you have completed the enrolment process and obtained the provisional ID from relevant State VAT department. In the event, the enrolment process is yet to commence in State in which you are registered as a VAT taxpayer, we would request you to confirm the receipt of the provisional ID at the earliest possible.</p>
<p>The process of enrolment and obtaining provisional IDs from State VAT department is provided on <a href="http://tutorial.gst.gov.in/video/module/index.html">http://tutorial.gst.gov.in/video/module/index.html</a>.&nbsp;</p>
<p>We have already have got the Provisional Registration Certificate and details of the same is provided below.</p>
<!--Left off format-->
<table cellpadding="5px" align="center" border="4">
<tbody>
<tr><th>Name of the Assesse</th><th>Provisional ID</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>Emerson Process Management Chennai Private Limited</td>
<td>33AAACF0483F1Z3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>We would also request you to identify and ascertain the HSN (Harmonized System of Nomenclature) number of the products supplied to us under the Agreement. Under the model GST laws, HSN code of the product must be mentioned in the invoice issued by you..</p>
<p>Separately, with the introduction of GST and model GST laws, the existing agreement needs be amended to incorporate for fresh/ revised covenants and obligations considering GST laws, and regarding revised commercials, as the parties may mutually decide. Accordingly, discussions in this regard would be initiated in due course.</p>
<p>We request you to provide your Provisional id details as per the below format:</p>
<table style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #00ff99; border-radius: 0px; text-align: center;" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#00ff99"><a style="display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; width: 500px; background-color: #00ff99; border: solid 1px #00ff99; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 12px 25px; text-transform: capitalize; border-color: #00ff99;" title="GSTN Number Updation" href="http://www.miisky.com/ci/index.php/Customerlink/vendorRecive/'.$vendor_id.'"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Click to view the GSTN Updation form</span></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>We hereby authorize M/S. Arms Value Chain Private Limited to collect and consolidate GST Registration details and request you to please share the details to them.</p>
<p>We look forward to your full support in smooth transition to the GST regime.</p>
<br />
<p>Best Regards,</p>
<p>S Hariharan <br /> Emerson Process Management Chennai Pvt. Ltd | 147, Rajiv Gandhi Salai (OMR) | Karapakkam Village | Chennai | 600097 | INDIA <br /> T +91 44 4903 4373 | F +91 44 4903 4400 <br /> <a href="mailto:hariharan.s@Emerson.com">hariharan.s@Emerson.com</a>
<p>CIN:U93090TN 1985 PTC 024245</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="footer" style="clear: both; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
<table style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="content-block" style="font-family: sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; text-align: center;" align="center" valign="top"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 13.3333px;"><span class="apple-link" style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;"><strong>Powered by:<a href="aarmsvaluechain.com">AARMS value chain pvt ltd</a></strong></span> <br /><br /></span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="content-block powered-by" style="font-family: sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; text-align: center;" align="center" valign="top"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">&nbsp;</span></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">&nbsp;</span></span></p>
<div>&nbsp;</div>';

$from_mail = 'your@vendor.com';
$from_name = 'GST-MIISKY';
$reply_to = 'innovations@miisky.com';
$subject = "Online GSTIN Updation!";

//$file_name = $datamail['varafile'];
//$path = realpath('uploads/abstract');

// Read the file content
//$file = $path . '/' . $file_name;

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->from($from_mail, $from_name);
$this->email->to($mail_id);
$this->email->cc('innovations@miisky.com');
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
//$this->email->attach($file);

}
if ($this->email->send()) {
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Mail Succesfully Sent!</div>');
redirect('Vendor_retrieve');
}
}   
}
```

***This is my view page***

```
<?php $firm_name = $this->session->userdata('firm_name');
if(!isset($firm_name)){ redirect ('Welcome');}
?>  
<link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/radiostyle.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet">  
<head>

  <style type="text/css">
  @import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css");
/* 
    FORM STYLING
*/
#fileselector {
    margin: 10px; 
}
#upload-file-selector {
    display:none;   
}
.margin-correction {
    margin-right: 10px;   
}
              .page-heading {
            border-top: 0;
            padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
        }
        input, button, select, textarea{
          margin: 10px;
        }
              .ibox-content {
          background-color: #ffffff;
          color: inherit;
          padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
          border-color: #e7eaec;
          border-image: none;
          border-style: none; 
          border-width: 1px 0px;
      }
      .filterable {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.filterable .panel-heading .pull-right {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled] {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.form-control, .single-line {
width: 90%;
}
.btn-group-xs>.btn, .btn-xs {
padding: 0px 15px;
line-height: 1;
}
.btn {
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.btn-info {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    color: #191717;
    font-weight: bolder;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
      </style>

</head>

            <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h1>GST - Vendor</h1>

                </div>
            </div>
           <br><div style="text-align: center;"> 
            <label class="control control--radio">Vendor
      <input type="radio" onclick="document.location='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Vendor_retrieve';" name="radio1" checked="checked" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--radio">Customer
      <input type="radio" onclick="document.location='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Customer_retrieve';" name="radio2"  />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--radio">Product
      <input type="radio" onclick="document.location='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Product_retrieve';" name="radio3" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
     <label class="control control--radio">Item
      <input type="radio" onclick="document.location='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Item_retrieve';" name="radio4" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label> 
      <label class="control control--radio">Rate
      <input type="radio" onclick="document.location='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Category_retrieve';" name="radio5" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
     <label class="control control--radio">Location
      <input type="radio" onclick="document.location='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Vendorlocation';" name="radio6" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>



    </div>
            <div class="fh-breadcrumb">

                <div class="full-height">
                    <div class="full-height-scroll white-bg border-left">
                    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
                       <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
                        <div class="element-detail-box">
                          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class='table table-bordered'>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                <th> # </th>
                <th> VendorID </th>
                <th> VendorCode </th>
                <th> VendorName </th>
                <th> VendorEmail </th>
                <th> VendorMobile </th>
                <th> VendorAddress </th>
                <th> Department </th>
                <th> Division </th>
                <th> State </th>
                <th> City </th>
                <th> CST_NO </th>
                <th> TIN_NO </th>
                <th> VAT_NO </th>
                <th> SGST_NO </th>
                <th> CGST_NO </th>
                <th> IGST_NO </th>
                <th> MSME_RegNO </th>
                <th> MSME_Category </th>
                <th> Send Mail</th>
                <th> Edit </th>
                <th> Delete </th>
              </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($catlist); ++$i) { ?>
                              <tr>
                                   <td><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->VendorID; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->VendorCode; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->VendorName; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->VendorEmail; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->VendorMobile; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->VendorAddress; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->Department; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->Division; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->State; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->City; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->CST_NO; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->TIN_NO; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->VAT_NO; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->SGST_NO; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->CGST_NO; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->IGST_NO; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->MSME_RegNO; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $catlist[$i]->MSME_Category; ?></td>
                                   <?php $encoded_mail = base64_encode($catlist[$i]->VendorEmail);?>
                                   <?php $encoded_id = base64_encode($catlist[$i]->VendorID);?>
                                   <td><?php echo anchor('Vendormail/index/'.$encoded_mail .'/'.$encoded_id , 'Send Mail', 'class="btn btn-info"');?></td>
                                   <td><a style="    background-color: rgba(106, 200, 35, 0.61);" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Vendor_retrieve/edit_data/<?php echo $catlist[$i]->VendorID?>" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</a></td>
                                   <!-- <td><?php echo anchor('Vendor_retrieve/edit_data/'.$catlist[$i]->VendorID, ' Edit');?></td> -->
                                   <td><a style="    background-color: #f85959;" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Vendor_retrieve/delete_data/<?php echo $catlist[$i]->VendorID?>" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Delete</a></td>
                                   <!-- <td><?php echo anchor('Vendor_retrieve/delete_data/'.$catlist[$i]->VendorID, ' Delete');?></td> -->
                              </tr>
                         <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>


          <a  <?php echo anchor('Send_all/index/'.$encoded_mail .'/'.$encoded_id , 'Send All', 'class="btn btn-info"');?></a>













                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
```

Comment: kindly provide the error your received

Comment: while click button in view page ...next come in  blank ...whether the code is correct are not i dont know..i will attach view page also u can check

Comment: while click save all button in view page..it is coming blank...pls help me

Comment: R u there..pls help me for this problem

Comment: post the error in your question so that other people will be able to understand faster your concerns.

Comment: are you checking this on localhost?

Comment: not sending email while click send all button...its coming blank

Comment: @NishantNair no live update..any solution

Comment: Is the page is blank check if the library/helper is loaded or not.

Comment: i have given library/helper in controller...code causing problem..whether function code is correct are not i dont know

Comment: pls check controller and tell me ...any error is there r not

Comment: take a look at your log file

Comment: k i will check this one...need to change any thing in view page for passing send all button

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: mail_to

Filename: controllers/Send_all.php

Line Number: 22- this error is coming while click send all button

Comment: pls check and tell me

Comment: @sintakonte r u there..

Comment: @sintakonte r u there..pls help me out

Comment: @NishantNair r u there

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it may help

```
 $this->load->library('email');
 $this->email->initialize($config);
```

replace your for each code

```
for($VendorEmail=0;$VendorEmail < count($cust_details);$VendorEmail++)
{}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137223/discussion-on-answer-by-nishant-nair-how-to-send-bulk-email-by-click-button-at-o).